# Not able to execute scripts from Jenkins although working fine locally & via command line

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I am Not able to run scripts from Jenkins. How ever working fine from Command line & Local. I am within office network. Getting Below Error. I don't understand why Jenkins is trying to download Maven plugin? I am new to Jenkins. Any suggestion will be appretiated.

```
[INFO] ------------------------< Test:Junit-Demo >-------------------------
[INFO] Building Junit-Demo 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom

    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 21.695 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-11T14:29:52-07:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.68.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
    Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"
    Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure

    Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Update the question with the `pom.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Maven, triggered by Jenkins, downloads the `maven-clean-plugin` as part of its normal execution. This happened on your location machine in the first run and was then cached in `~/.m2/`.

Your Jenkins build agent, however, cannot connect to the server from which maven downloads artifacts:

> Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.68.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Make sure that there is no firewall involved blocking these connections or configure Jenkins to use a local artifact repository (like Nexus or Artifactory).

Answer (score 0):

Missing some info to fully know what's wrong.

To use maven in Jenkins you have to install the jenkins maven plugin and call the binary in your Jenkins file.

Did you have to do any maven configuration for your local set up?

ie inside ~/.m2 is usually where you would set up your account for nexus credentials inside settings.xml.

You would have to do this same config on your jenkins machine, either in the Jenkins user account's ~/.m2 or inside the maven plugin folder.